# How do I stop Netbeans from autocompleting anything I don't ask it to?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, quotes, brackets

Just started using Netbeans again for the first time in a few years, and it keeps changing all my damn code.

I love that it gives dropdowns for autocompletions, but I HATE that it automatically moves my quotes and brackets all the time, even after I've turned off quote completion in PHP and HTML settings.  It also insists on auto concatenating my strings every time I press return within a set of quotes (ie changing a quoted paragraph into concatenated quoted lines).

Is there a way to turn off ALL of this behaviour?  It seems like every single time it guesses something it gets it wrong, and it seems a shame that an otherwise very good IDE is ruined by something so stupid.

I just want to type my code without it changing anything!!!